# How to WriteValue to GATT Characteristic with DBus and Bluez 5.41?

Tags: ruby, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez, gatt

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy Sensor I'm trying to use through the DBus interface.  The basic procedure (after connection) is to Write a 1 to a characteristic to turn on the temperature sensor, wait a second, get a reading from another characteristic and then write a 0 back to the original characteristic to turn it off again.  I am able to write to these in the shell using gatttool in interactive mode, but every time I attempt writing a value using WriteValue using DBus I get Error.NotSupported (DBus::Error) in my Ruby code.  I also get what looks like the same error using d-feet DBus debugger.  I can ReadValue and read properies in the GattCharacteristic1 interface just fine.

I have tried all kinds of formats for writing bytes, writing a a DBus.variant offset of zero and other things and the error does not seem to go away.  I'm able to read from both d-feet and my own code.  I'm using Ruby and the dbus-ruby gem, but I don't believe this is specific to the Ruby code.

```
c = get_obj_iface("#{device}/service0022/char0023", 'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1')

puts c.ReadValue({}).inspect #works and outputs [[0, 0, 0, 0]]

bytes = [0, 0, 0, 0].pack('C*') #byte array w/ 4 bytes since that is what I get when I read

c.WriteValue(bytes, {} ) #also tried with {'offset' => DBus.variant('q', 0) }
```

These are some screen shots of similar problems in d-feet DBus debugger.

[image: The WriteValue fails].

[image: The ReadValue and other properties work fine].

As you can see in d-feet, writing also fails where reading works just fine.  What am I doing wrong here, or could this be a problem in bluez or with the way my sensor is set up?

Comment: What is the xml definition of the dbus interface? I've found only the one with "ay" parameter type: array and byte. Can't see a string/variant dictionary there. Also, there must be the sources for that bluez daemon to dig in. Or launch that daemon under `strace` to see if it's doing anything when receiving the `WriteValue`: something should do an `open` or `write` on that char device in the end.

Comment: The signature is a{sv}.  Right now I'm leaving the dict empty since I don't particularly want to set any values.

Comment: Oops, accidentally pressed enter. ... I tried with {"offset": GLib.Variant('q', 0)} in d-feet (Python) and {'offset' => DBus.variant('q', 0) } in Ruby.  http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt has the documentation.  I grepped through the C source a bit and found the error messages & where the WriteValue method was (like GDBUS_EXPERIMENTAL_ASYNC_METHOD("WriteValue", GDBUS_ARGS({ "value", "ay" },{ "options", "a{sv}" }) ).  Sorry, a long time since I've worked with C. strace is a good idea.

Comment: I tried `ReadValue()` with the string `{"offset": GLib.Variant("q", 0)}` and it returned an empty array. The variation `{"offset": __import__('gi.repository.GLib', globals(), locals(), ['Variant']).Variant("q", 0)}` also worked. **NOTE:** in order to make the first command work, you might need to install `python-gobject` and `python-dbus`.